# Python 2.7 - Thread-safe and url keyword not recognized in eclipse with google app engine SDK and Pydev

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Eclipse with Pydev and googleAppengine. I have python 2.7 installed. I am trying to run the easiest first program about hello world which is available here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld.html

The problem is my app.yaml is not recognizing ***Thread-safe*** and ***url*** keyword. It's giving the error message that it's not spelled correctly.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

My code:
App.yaml:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

and
helloworld.py:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Why do you care what Eclipse thinks? Surely the only thing that matters is whether the code works?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the SDK? What's the actual error message, and what are you doing to generate it?

Comment: It's working now. Thanks Daniel - you are right I should not worry about eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 isn't yet supported via the Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: It is, but the Eclipse plugin hasn't caught up to it yet.